# create main and submenu - one below the other - with nested ul - without position absolute

Tags: html, css

I don't know how to do this without position absolute (the sub-ul must stay nested).

http://codepen.io/elkeschiffer/pen/WrjEwe

May someone can help me please?
Is there a way?

```css
* {
      list-style:none;
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
    }

    ul {
      display:block;
      width:100%;
      text-align:center;
      position:relative;
    }

    ul ul {
      position:absolute;
      top:100%;
      left:0;
      background-color:#333;
      color:#fff;
    }

    li {
      padding:5px;
      display:inline-block;
    }

    a {
      color:inherit;
      text-decoration:none;
    }
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Fair</a></li>
    <li>Energy
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Beratung &amp; Bau</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Photovoltaik</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" title="Partner">Partner</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="Wissen">Wissen</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: check http://www.devinrolsen.com/wp-content/themes/dolsen/demos/css/infinite-sub-menu/

Comment: I don't understand.. `without position absolute` `. Have you just one sub menu? 2. Are you want to show it only when parent's `hover`? 3. If you don't use `position:absolute` you content will "jump" whenever the submenu will show. Is that what you want?

Comment: There will be more than one sub menu and it will be shown independently of hover.

Yes, I want the content react to each other.

Comment: Just curious, what's wrong with `position:absolute`?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with position:absolute but in that case I need a solution without - because I want the following content to follow the menu without a gap. regardless of how many levels there will be.

Comment: My easy solution would be seperate lists but for web accessibility I thought the menu should be nested (for navigating using a keyboard).

Comment: I suspect you'll need javascript in that case.

Comment: Oh, I hoped for a solution without javascript.
Maybe I will change the tabindex and use seperated ul.